# Laravel - Getting a undefined method Collection::touchOwners on server but not localy

Tags: php, database, post, laravel, eloquent

Just deployed and testing out the app and I am facing a strange issue, when trying to update a user profile I get a 
Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::touchOwners()` 
Which absolutely does not occur when runing the app localy! I checked the tables and they do have the right updated_at and created_at so I know it is not coming from there. 
I also changed some lines where I was using create instead of save but still nothing.

Would you have a lead I could investigate? I don't think dropping the whole code here will change anything unless you can think of something specific that could be the problem. So here is just an example:

```
$user -> address_id     = $address_id;
$user -> gender_id      = $gender_id;
$user -> first_name     = $first_name;
$user -> last_name      = $last_name;
$user -> birthdate      = $birthdate;
$user -> description    = $description;

if ($user->save()) {
    return Redirect::route('profile-user', $user -> username)
        ->with('global', 'Your details have been updated.');
} else {
    return Redirect::route('profile-update')
        ->with('global', 'There was a problem updating your profile.')
        ->withInput();
}
```

I tried to set `['touch' => false]` but that doesn't change anything
Thanks!

Comment: There's a bug with `belongsToMany` and `touches` property. So just don't use `touching` with this kind of relation for now and it won't be a problem.

Comment: what would you recommend doing? Even the['touch' => false] didn't work... and it is really strange I get the bug in the production version and not the local..

Comment: Like I said, don't use `touches` property for `belongsToMany` relations. And if you use `$user->save(['touch' => false])` then it won't trigger this bug for sure. About local and production - this bug exists since v4.2.9 so probably you have earlier version in local env.

Comment: Will try it again thanks!